# How to display JSON information using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am creating a file that displays a json file using AJAX. The problem I have right now is it only prints the first row, I want it to print all 4 rows. I tried adding another print statement under my original one in json.php but that just caused errors.

Here is the function for json in my index.html file

```
function getJSON() {
        var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
        if (!xmlHttp) {
                alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
                return;
        }

        xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {

                        // Get Response Text
                        var response = xmlHttp.responseText;

                        // Prints the JSON string
                        console.dir(response);

                        // Get div object
                        var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoJSON');

                        // We used JSON.parse to turn the JSON string into an object
                        var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);

                        // This is our object
                        console.dir(responseObject);


                        // We can use that object like so:
                        divObj.innerHTML = responseObject.name + " lived during the " + responseObject.pet;

                }
        }

        xmlHttp.open("GET", "json.php", true);
        xmlHttp.send();
}
```

json.php

```
<?php
    // Print the json
    $result = array('name' => 'Staurikosaurus', 'pet' => 'Triassic');
    $result2 = array('name' => 'Diplodocus', 'pet' => 'Jurassic');
    $result3 = array('name' => 'Stegosaurus', 'pet' => 'Jurassic');
    $result4 = array('name' => 'Tyrannosaurus', 'pet' => 'Cretaceous');

    print json_encode($result);

?>
```

ajax.js

```
function xmlHttpObjCreate() {
 var xmlHttp;
 try
  {
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 catch (e)
  {
    try
 {
 xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 }
 catch (e)
 {
 try
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 catch (e)
  {
  return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
 }
```

so right now when the button is pressed my program displays this:

```
Staurikosaurus lived during the Triassic
```

and I want my program to display this

```
Staurikosaurus lived during the Triassic 
Diplodocus lived during the Jurassic 
Stegosaurus lived during the Jurassic 
Tyrannosaurus lived during the Cretaceous
```

Comment: You are only returning the first array (`$result`) and not the others (`$result2,$result3,$result4`). I suggest adding each row to one array, return the json_encoded array, then loop through the response in javascript.

Comment: @showdev how would I do that?

Comment: Can I combine them all into 1 array somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning the first array (`$result`) and not the others (`$result2,$result3,$result4`).

I suggest adding each pair of values to one array:

```php
$result=array(
    array('name' => 'Staurikosaurus', 'pet' => 'Triassic'),
    array('name' => 'Diplodocus', 'pet' => 'Jurassic'),
    array('name' => 'Stegosaurus', 'pet' => 'Jurassic'),
    array('name' => 'Tyrannosaurus', 'pet' => 'Cretaceous')
);
```

Then output the json_encoded array:

```
print json_encode($result,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Which should give you a JSON object like this:

```json
{  
    "0":{  
        "name":"Staurikosaurus",
        "pet":"Triassic"
    },
    "1":{  
        "name":"Diplodocus",
        "pet":"Jurassic"
    },
    "2":{  
        "name":"Stegosaurus",
        "pet":"Jurassic"
    },
    "3":{  
        "name":"Tyrannosaurus",
        "pet":"Cretaceous"
    }
}
```

Then loop through the result with JavaScript, something like this (but output however you choose):

```
for (i in response) {
    var line = document.createElement('p');
    line.innerHTML = response[i].name + ' lived during the ' + response[i].pet + ' period.'
    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(line);
}
```

### EDIT:

Or, to format it more like your code, this:

```
// We can use that object like so:
for (i in responseObject) {
    divObj.innerHTML += "<p>"+responseObject[i].name + " lived during the " + responseObject[i].pet + "period.</p>";
}
```

```js
var responseObject = {  
    "0":{  
        "name":"Staurikosaurus",
        "pet":"Triassic"
    },
    "1":{  
        "name":"Diplodocus",
        "pet":"Jurassic"
    },
    "2":{  
        "name":"Stegosaurus",
        "pet":"Jurassic"
    },
    "3":{  
        "name":"Tyrannosaurus",
        "pet":"Cretaceous"
    }
};


// Get div object
var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoJSON');

// Loop through JSON
for (i in responseObject) {
    divObj.innerHTML += "<p>"+responseObject[i].name + " lived during the " + responseObject[i].pet + " period.</p>";
}
```

```html
<div id="dinoJSON"></div>
```

Comment: Wait so where do I add it into my index.html file? the code to loop through the JavaScript. The place where I added it gave me an error

Comment: Put the `for` loop where you have `// We can use that object like so:`. Note that you are using the variable `responseObject` rather than `response`, so adjust for that when you use the loop.

Comment: I'm so confused now, I tried the people below way and it didn't work. Im going to try yours now

Comment: If you like, edit your question to show what you're trying and let us know what goes wrong.

Comment: I get this error now Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null index.html:line 74
This line is the "document.getElementById('output').appendChild(line);" line

Comment: You may not have an element `<div id="output"></div>`. That was just my way of outputting the result to the screen for testing. I have updated my answer to reflect your code.

Answer (score 0):

My bad deleted the other answer try changing your json array to something like this.

```
$result = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Staurikosaurus",
        "pet" => "Triassic"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Diplodocus",
        "pet'" => "Jurassic"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Stegosaurus",
        "pet'" => "Jurassic"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Tyrannosaurus",
        "pet'" => "Cretaceous"
    )
);
print json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Think someone beat me too it :P

Comment: it prints out this now "undefined lived during the undefined"

Comment: `$result = array(
    array(
        "name" => "Staurikosaurus",
        "pet" => "Triassic"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Diplodocus",
        "pet" => "Jurassic"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Stegosaurus",
        "pet" => "Jurassic"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Tyrannosaurus",
        "pet" => "Cretaceous"
    )
);`

Comment: @ryan jimmy - was my fault had a `'` where it did not belong should work now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    // Print the json
    $result[] = array('name' => 'Staurikosaurus', 'pet' => 'Triassic');
    $result[] = array('name' => 'Diplodocus', 'pet' => 'Jurassic');
    $result[] = array('name' => 'Stegosaurus', 'pet' => 'Jurassic');
    $result[] = array('name' => 'Tyrannosaurus', 'pet' => 'Cretaceous');

    print json_encode($result);

?>
```

The problem is that you're only printing the first array that's why you only see it print the first row.

Comment: I tried this and its output was this 
"undefined lived during the undefined"

Comment: You have to loop it to get each value, because it's an array.

Comment: where do I put this loop?

Comment: on your front-end script when you get the array value from an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display on a webpage or something like that you could just do php by itself and do something like this.

```
$result = array( array( 'name' => 'Staurikosaurus', 'pet' => 'Triassic' ), array( 'name' => 'Diplodocus', 'pet' => 'Jurassic' ), array( 'name' => 'Stegosaurus', 'pet' => 'Jurassic' ), array( 'name' => 'Tyrannosaurus', 'pet' => 'Cretaceous' ) );
foreach ($result as $names){
    echo $names['name'].' lived during the '.$names['pet'].'<br />';
}
```

which would output this

```
Staurikosaurus lived during the Triassic
Diplodocus lived during the Jurassic
Stegosaurus lived during the Jurassic
Tyrannosaurus lived during the Cretaceous
```